# java.security.SignatureException Signature length not correct: got 128 but was expecting 512

Tags: java, security, jce, opensaml

I am using Shiboleth opensaml (http://shibboleth.net/downloads/java-opensaml/) library for SAML and recently, after upgrading the libraries (the reason for upgrade was a NoSuchMethodError), the server started throwing the following exception during server start up:

[SigningUtil] Verifying signature over input using public key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA1withRSA
[SigningUtil] Error during signature verification
Caused by:
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 128 but was expecting 512

Generally, what causes this issue? This was not occurring on my local Windows system.( JVM:  1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 24.71-b01) OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64) but only on Linux based system.

Looking forward to some suggestions or point me to some articles. Thanks in advance.